# What are the Jena methods used to access an ontology?

Tags: java, jsp, owl, jena

Hello I'm new to ontologies, my assignment is to create an ontology using Protege V4.0.2, (which I've done) and to create a website over that ontology(which I'm working on),
i just need the basics on how to search the ontology using the Jena library
I dont have any specifics because i haven't yet started.
but i'm in a time crunch, and i need to now exactly how i'm goning to do it

Comment: I think it's a classic RTFM question ;-) But I don't think it deserves the -1 you received from someone.... so I've made it +1 myself so its back at zero.

Comment: The problem is i don't have FM to read. but thnx

Comment: removed the NetBeans tag, since this really isn't about NetBeans usage and/or APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading (simplest method):

- http://jena.sourceforge.net/how-to/filemanager.html
- http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/FileManager.html

Query using SPARQL:

- http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/Tutorial/

Ontology API:

- http://jena.sourceforge.net/ontology/index.html

A quick way to get started in Netbeans is using a maven project. Add jena and arq to the library and they will be downloaded by maven.